# Enable or disable button based on radio button does not work in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written in aspx file as

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Add As a Sub Organization" OnClick="lnkChild_Click" ValidationGroup="GroupA" class="btn-u" CausesValidation="true" />

    <asp:GridView ID="grdDuplicateOrganisationList" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" CssClass="table"
            DataKeyNames="OrganisationId" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Organization">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="text-align: left">
                            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdoOrganisation" GroupName="Child" onclick="javascript:CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVID(this);"></asp:RadioButton>
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                </columns>
             </asp:GridView>

    <script type="text/javascript">
// function alert() { return confirm("Your Message was sent successfully!") } $(function () { $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover() })



$(function () {
    if (!($('#<%= grdDuplicateOrganisationList.ClientID %> tr td').find('input:radio').is(':checked'))) {
                       $('#<%= btn.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', true).attr('title', 'Select organization then click...');
                   }
               });

               $('#<%= grdDuplicateOrganisationList.ClientID %> tr td').find('input:radio').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#<%= btn.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', false).attr('title', '');
                   } else {
        $('#<%= btn.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', true).attr('title', 'Select organization then click...');
                   }

            });

</script>
```

Now I want that If user will click on radio button then btn should be enabled. 
The above JavaScript does not work.

Comment: `$('input:radio').change(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
alert('check')
$('input:button').prop('disabled',false);
}else{
alert('notcheck')
$('input:button').prop('disabled',true);
}
})`

Comment: Sorry I am not getting it...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0w9fve3L/5/

Comment: Instead of posting the ASP, could you post the actual outputed HTML/JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't any idea about asp but the question is about Jquery so May be I could help you

```
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="1">Toggle

<script type="text/javascript">

   $("input[name=toggle]").on('click', function() {
   var checked = $("input[name=toggle]").prop('checked');
  console.log(checked);
   if(checked) { $("#yourbtnId").show();  } 
  else { $("#yourbtnId").hide(); }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o5myvgp9/1/

**Edit**

You can also set it on dom ready

```
  $(function() {
        var checked = $("input[name=toggle]").prop('checked');
        console.log(checked);
        if(checked) { $("#yourbtnId").show();  } 
        else { $("#yourbtnId").hide(); }
  });
```